# Best practice to handle async events and run huge post-processing code

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, event-handling, .net-4.0

## Async event handler

I have this class to run an executable asynchronously:

```cs
namespace Feather
{
    internal class Helper
    {
        private static Process cmd;

        public static void RunLogic(string args)
        {
            cmd = new Process();

            cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "Cotton.exe";
            cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = args;
            cmd.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            cmd.Exited += new EventHandler(cmd_Exited);
        }

        private static void cmd_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Process finished.
            cmd.Dispose();

            // An output file is generated by the executable.
            // The output file needs post-processing.
            // Post-processing is a huge code base.
            // TODO: Best practice to run huge post-processing code here?
        }
    }
}
```

## Trigger

I trigger exe to run from within another class like this:

```cs
namespace Feather
{
    public class FeatherHollow : Command
    {

        protected override Result RunCommand(RhinoDoc doc, RunMode mode)
        {
            string args = "";

            // Trigger async run of the executable.
            Helper.RunLogic(args);

            // TODO: How to run the huge post-processing code when the output file
            // is generated by the executable.

            return Result.Success;
        }
    }
}
```

## Question

What is the best practice and simplest way to run a huge post-processing code when the async process finishes?

## `delegate` approach

Is this the best way?

```cs
namespace Feather
{
    internal class Helper
    {
        public delegate void PostProcess(object sender, EventArgs e);

        public static void RunLogic(string args, PostProcess pp)
        {
                // ...
                cmd.Exited += new EventHandler(cmd_Exited);
                cmd.Exited += new EventHandler(pp);
                // ...
        }
    }
}
```

And caller class:

```cs
namespace Feather
{
    public class FeatherHollow : Command
    {
        protected override Result RunCommand(RhinoDoc doc, RunMode mode)
        {
            // ...
            Helper.RunLogic(args, PostProcess);
            // ...
        }

        private static void PostProcess(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Huge post-processing code is here.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How about putting the post-processing code inside the `cmd_Exited` event handler? What's wrong with that?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias The `RunLogic` is triggered by various classes/methods with different post-processing requirements.

Comment: So your question is how to make the `string args` visible to the code inside the `cmd_Exited` handler?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I updated my question with an option that I have. It would also make my question more clear.

Comment: To be honest it's still not clear to me what you are asking. Trying to infer your question by comparing code snippets is too hard work for my sleepy and caffeine-deprived mind. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using Task and async await:

```
public static Task RunLogic(string args, CancellationToken cancel = default)
{
    cmd = new Process();
    // ...

   return cmd.WaitForExitAsync(cancel);
}
```

This lets you use await when calling the method, and that tend to make the code simpler to read than using delegates/callbacks.

```
await RunLogic(...);
// do post process stuff
```

If you want to return a value from `RunLogic`:

```
public static async Task<string> RunLogic(string args, CancellationToken cancel = default)
{
    cmd = new Process();
    // ...

   await cmd.WaitForExitAsync(cancel);
   
   return myResultValue;
}
```

If you are using an older version of .Net, you can replicate the same functionality using [`TaskCompletionSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcompletionsource-1?view=net-7.0).

Comment: Thanks :) Looks good. By the `Task` approach, I can avoid freezing my app when the processing and post-processing are happening. Right? I intend to keep the app responsive while the process and post-process are being done.

Comment: @Megidd depends on what you are doing. If the post processing is CPU intensive, or use blocking IO, it will still block the (UI?) thread, unless you move execution to a background thread, for example using `Task.Run`. Just make sure your code is thread safe if you do that.

Comment: Maybe using the [`Process.WaitForExitAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexitasync) is simpler (and safer) than messing with `TaskCompletionSource`s.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Thanks, I keep forgetting about the .Net core+ APIs.